# pygame, Is this the correct way to use classes?

Tags: python, pygame

I recently have started to learn classes, I am pretty new to classes, so my question is, am I using it correctly and also what are the advantages of using a class because I'm not sure if I need them but I feel like without it my code will feel lengthy and messy, if you could show me an example of how you used classes, I would appreciate it, if you could include a complex and simple class example please I think that would help me understand,thank you!
quick note about this code, this is based on my other code but this one is using classes instead.

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
display_w = 800
display_h = 600

window = pygame.display.set_mode((display_w, display_h), HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF | RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("game_icon.png"))
pygame.display.set_caption("Work in progress")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.image.load("background.png")


class Player(object):
    """The controllable player in game"""

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, speed):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprite_sheet.png")
        self.speed = speed

    def draw(self):
        self.sprite = (self.image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 100, 50, 50)))
        window.blit(self.sprite, (self.x, self.y))

    def movement(self):
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= self.speed
        if self.keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += self.speed
        if self.keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= self.speed
        if self.keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += self.speed


player = Player(400, 300, 50, 50, 5)

running = True
while running:
    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), RESIZABLE)

    player.draw()
    player.movement()

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Yes, the only thing you could do to make it better is to move `self.sprite = (self.image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 100, 50, 50)))` to `__init__` so its one less thing the program has to do each frame and will very slightly increase performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems a good start.

If you are working in pygame, you should like look at using Sprites and Sprite Groups. You would make your player a subclass of Sprite.

See [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) for the docs. It is a little more to learn how to use and you need to understand inheritance in classes, but it is worth the effort. I would start using it before you get going to far.

Also you should use pygames `Rect` class instead of keeping separate x, y, height and width attributes. The `Rect` class is very useful in a lot of ways and often simplifies the code. It also has built in collision routines. Also many pygame calls expect a `Rect` argument. See [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for the docs.

There are some examples of using Sprites in pygame [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/examples.html).